# GET request works on local machine but doesn't work on Linux server

Tags: node.js, https, get

For the Discord bot, I need to send a GET request to a specific service to shorten a specific link.
I am using the https module from NPM to send a GET request, namely:

```
    var https= require('https');
    let opts = {
      host: 'clicksfly.com',
      path: '/api?api=SECRETCODEd&format=text&url=www.google.com',
      method: 'GET'
    };
    const req = https.request(opts, res => {

        res.on('data', d => {
            console.log(d.toString());
        });
    });
    req.end();
```

This code works completely on my computer, and it returns a shortcut link. However, on the server where my bot is located, this code does not work, namely, it sends a long code of an incomprehensible HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA
-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Just a moment...</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-family:-apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, "Helvetica Neue",Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.7em;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
    h1 { text-align: center; font-weight:700; margin: 16px 0; font-size: 32px; color:#000000; line-height: 1.25;}
    p {font-size: 20px; font-weight: 400; margin: 8px 0;}
    p, .attribution, {text-align: center;}
    #spinner {margin: 0 auto 30px auto; display: block;}
    .attribution {margin-top: 32px;}
    @keyframes fader     { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
    @-webkit-keyframes fader { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles { animation: fader 1.6s infinite;}
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .2s;}
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .4s;}
    .bubbles { background-color: #f58220; width:20px; height: 20px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; display:inline-block; }
    a { co
lor: #2c7cb0; text-decoration: none; -moz-transition: color 0.15s ease; -o-transition: color 0.15s ease; -webkit-transition: color 0.15s ease; transition: color 0.15s ease; }
    a:hover{color: #f4a15d}
    .attribution{font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5;}
    .ray_id{display: block; margin-top: 8px;}
    #cf-wrapper #challenge-form { padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px; }
    #cf-hcaptcha-container { text-align:center;}
    #cf-hcaptcha-container iframe { display: inline-block;}
  </style>

      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){

      window._cf_chl_opt={
        cvId: "2",
        cType: "non-interactive",
        cNounce: "24390",
        cRay: "6c53b849cf342c52",
        cHash: "d48c5950487c1fc",
        cPMDTk: "TGRJIKcYNeQaUi4qjEFvtSSBAfHY03rt_7_2xESZg24-1640788159-0-gaNycGzNBuU",
        cFPWv: "g",
        cTTimeMs: "1000",
        cRq: {
          ru: "aHR0cHM6Ly9jbGlja3NmbHkuY29tL2FwaT9hcGk9Yjg4YjhjZDg5MjBmNzZjYTBhMDcwYmM1ZDQ2MmI5MWQ4NmNmMGI1ZCZmb3JtYXQ9dGV4dCZ1cmw9d3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20=",
          ra: "",
          rm: "R0VU",
          d: "47w2TkCdqOr0Tck9v6/aqzyT2lSjPuS81Akssy/HzRxaWwidLLHW74f1FOQUFn/lAWOf/De/txE6ePHyUXrUmXM3ltJ8BE5ZvBPCPF8n2muZ2XR33mqdLzTVcErGWEq0YeyjdXkgvNvZTVfkM70rOAHAYJb2suMmaUae91VBgKpIVnkw26Wwr7P9mFqluxpQREHJ+QAxC4CpNsMdQOYJD7GNYns
Pr+wFSJihZBiPymo8rx4Uegxcnf9sJhvItS7WDNrr5Eja/zEf4hnTasqLHeOknNIJ9np06y0fspnkEF6/qDgp4NSQdLEYV5pkbwXCqbEOfuBX3fGRuX0+qajK1exUUGPxLrzqL37mdD/fNA0wYhiDSZS2BHHlyler2S88M7vXBvLBNM78BQmVEan/CTnzck3sGqUgs40Ckhy4HEncspT7Lu87RPsqQ8kf/qiC8IDxLRDOGnJF5AThherCErcAv7zUi6gVr5bB5/qEW74Rp8c1Q1vwAImtYNC0SxPJ5LbgnUdOUeUhHUe0s5Rw4Dx7zIbHA9VpMpyAhemSaHA=",
          t: "MTY0MDc4ODE1OS4wMTEwMDA=",
          m: "f24BKfHcLktTTQE1Q1/kNNARn0oM+B4CwSSsUmvRs6g=",
          i1: "+c9VZZ25U4G4BasL/L05rg==",
          i2: "Kz28rQ4qA6UO6XV/AQmYsA==",
          zh: "va4hCvZPZYx/dl/GK/fh92PoHUPArv8s552Q7x2/qYo=",
          uh: "DV4j3Tmrbi5Rs1q3ahwVS6SgbPbI7np5884QO1u1Cgg=",
          hh: "pl7IslarvVZvfg0YHKRLaukHlDa0TtpfuYJctN/tpqM=",
        }
      }
      window._cf_chl_enter = function(){window._cf_chl_opt.p=1};

    })();
    //]]>
  </script>


</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="20">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
          <div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
  <noscript>
    <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
  </noscript>
  <div id="cf-content" style="display:none">

    <div id="cf-bubbles">
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
    </div>
    <h1><span dat
a-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> clicksfly.com.</h1>

    <div id="no-cookie-warning" class="cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="display:none">
      <p data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">Please enable Cookies and reload the page.</p>
    </div>
    <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
    <p data-translate="allow_5_secs" id="cf-spinner-allow-5-secs" >Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>
    <p data-translate="redirecting" id="cf-spinner-redirecting" style="display:none">Redirecting&hellip;</p>
  </div>

  <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/api?api=b88b8cd8920f76ca0a070bc5d462b91d86cf0b5d&amp;format=text&amp;url=www.google.com&amp;__cf_chl_f_tk=TGRJIKcYNeQaUi4qjEFvtSSBAfHY03rt_7_2xESZg24-1640788159-0-gaNycGzNBuU" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="md" value="xkEcrpi8t1.QjXZlqCsIjpdEGmDY_IdcgbTeOQYnWyM-1640788159-0-AVJqqT9Tvcgthj9NRbMs79IOh1RWvyCKlp7aD5F_0fTulpLPDbF-RLTYMcO9QsWjbBGbgh_Wc6nalQ5OfQ5AfETkxDG89DCtXBs8eS12TTViPp2xtMEUwLQfccIK6xA-lcZ4eYMUD7iGkWMVnLq0WPsKybj52VXST_RhKTB-_CYc8HLABUkmygvc7bzMkoratKKK7jNCM_kV2ROIF-sxykIOseW9Qzg7-8xGIN55DCtQdF-AGg6P5EZPgZ--6fgAXmpDOt6HdnUfRXOy
sjKKD1m0LEswX3mcqY2AQnh1ocfg4rXbBy7FwTX2SHRb0qWbQ96DC5Jw6uq4NuqzYdbTiRNx_jq2Kujxhu5F74LpJQfxBR13hujaoqODdBxhbl3m-X9EzNNloGdNgK5ahkTD9BtUPMaYL_bsygKJXLtlkq7sUsGB3OxPsKFFb87UfgaSWXTc0HrXoRXoa1f91kRM02RyBnbOzu6eV4BA0-hfaW0n3oO7LkKoSbXuibYYst4Y1I21_-BxrFE5r23okOcM698KGlACH9TzAbBmEx0H_k1P1J99RPV4od1oBfQrDCbfE6Hwehaj77g63-NwfMUtweEEG_Iegj-7gJIsmTdpGqENcIgZzBkVWJoQyJtmkvkQSRqBGrauqvLZuUpT4J2JcwRwPs-ybpK7WKKzRyOA2vK2UrrjRpQrhIhqj7ay7Cz1eWiyJXnwPvzu3wRfE5t3CHMU0od5eKuEdh0Ruq1y6Tj7n22ho9sn92vPwWkVdk9CeT101bJ83LRrJk3XPvIOi1E" />
    <input type="hidden" name="r" value="EfcTylAJ6D0BDns4eSFtNCPUpLdh4A7kjPglrCzMQeo-1640788159-0-AanhkUrahNV4ONtYb+sTo+uauUtmeERPrcNryzlJIFlv4alUyU7Lhm1SHiFYP9lTDLGxy6PM9+uYgtQ3AXWBqoUr39qaO6Kto/d9EArJN8X52JJkzrLUVcoj//vu++QxzuTIsT0NhOLdCTIYZzGxDsCSzhYEIQ8iGpN8u+eBdcBgQkvZUNlETgynelJUNpjv5x3CX9nfBo0C/WlEjYWhC++TP68liuZatG0bIA2uxXOfopNCMch5xtiulF9GYMafWhIwxVM1+LHYAscRN+PUhZluA1+6tpkLyMneVRry2+3LA0I3zRET0Vq/5Z+MYRrwLU7XdpAWqDyFQPN/YsG4V5qWdwX2NKsLRzP6dxwbvrX14NFpP6Xrsj8Dr9PAs1zPce2gETT3Wv5LpDeUbX9k/Tlf1IkLhLse2Kx0giwa9dI5vEZb1SavlGYkGKUXPJmc80gocm+WvZVUcNiXbkLnlXixbbCcKQzLMK1e9rZIrLJv7kuzlIar/hd9A7otR5+I5iUIUnnnyWLJjuYcnN3+c9W9r0clCPtT+GpMAPkjz5boWU1PgJbUEH8JpFicCDy9cJcui+VXNe1b6GQgSwPZl0ABjzTqfWxVWjgxYnA1Jz+euFT2BSlEIvGg2Mhj4bJNa2RcbwmnBT3stMObWg3JS9IivnBZmkUsprWiPr07qr/FAWSRpjYpykmCp7CEgssEKbGwk7fUc43RlJclVKyW8R00JN7BpQH/44TwKPrKN9G
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"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="133b40e5940ea08e8901277e08bc72e4" id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc"/>
    <!-- <input type="hidden" value="" id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc"/> -->
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1640788160.011-Z8znjbzNhw"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
  </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      (function(){

      var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');
          a.style.display = 'block';
          var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
          var trkjs = isIE ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
          trkjs.setAttribute("src", "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/js/transparent.gif?ray=6c53b849cf342c52");
          trkjs.id = "trk_jschal_js";
          trkjs.setAttribute("alt", "");
          document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
          var cpo=document.createElement('script');
          cpo.type='text/javascript';
          cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/jsch/v1?ray=6c53b849cf342c52";

          if (window._cf_chl_opt.cPMDTk && window.history && window.history.replaceState && window.URLSearchParams) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + location.search + location.hash;
            var p = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
            p.set('__cf_chl_rt_tk', window._cf_chl_opt.cPMDTk);
            history.replaceState(null, null, location.pathname + '?' + p.toString() + location.hash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
              history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
          }

          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
        }());
      //]]>
    </script>



  <div id="trk_jschal_nojs" style=
"background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=6c53b849cf342c52')"> </div>
</div>

          <div style="display: none;"><a href="https://tempestsw.com/nightingalesguilt.php?c=0">table</a></div>
          <div class="attribution">
            DDoS protection by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing/" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a>
            <br />
            <span class="ray_id">Ray ID: <code>6c53b849cf342c52</code></span>
          </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use CURL instead of modules, however the same problem occurred with it, but that did not lead me to a possible solution, and also tried to use other modules to send the request, however with them the same problem.

Also, I found out that this HTML code is associated specifically with the site of the link shortening service, but, as you understand, I want to refer to the service API.